# Maya Python: create one cluster for multiple curve cvs

Tags: python, cluster-computing, maya, autodesk

Alright, so now I'm on the last problem with my spine autorigger: instead of posting the full code however, I simplified the question down to a basic demo. Here is what I want to do:

I know how to use a For Loop to make all the cvs on a curve get clustered: but instead of all the cvs: I want it to just cluster the top 2 cvs, then the bottom 2 cvs for a total of 2 clusters instead of the 4 it creates for the guideLine_ctrlCurve

Second, I would like it to rename the clusters. I can hardcode the cluster names: but that isn't reliable since clusters still get named incrementally by maya even if you change the names of the previous clusters

Third: I want it to parent the renamed clusters under clusterGrp: the problem is however: whenver you parent a cluster it automatically creates a new group for the cluster which can be super annoying: the only way I've found around this is dragging the cluster in the outliner under the new parent: but I have not found a python solution.

```
'''
import DS_clusterCurve_demo
reload (DS_clusterCurve_demo)
DS_clusterCurve_demo.gui()
'''

import re
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

if cmds.window("clusterWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("clusterWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("clusterWin",t='DS_clusterCurve_demo',w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui():
    if cmds.window("clusterWin", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("clusterWin", window=True)

    myWindow = cmds.window("clusterWin", t="DS_clusterCurve_demo", w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
    column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

    cmds.button(label="Build Example curve", c=buildExamples)
    cmds.separator(w=200, h=3)
    cmds.button(label="Create Curve Clusters", c=buildClusters)
    cmds.separator(w=200, h=3)
    cmds.button(label="Group Clusters", c=groupClusters)

    cmds.setParent("..")
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

def buildExamples(*args):
    cmds.curve(n='guideLine_ctrlCurve', d=1, p=[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(0,3,0)])

def buildClusters(*args):
    curveCVs = cmds.ls('guideLine_ctrlCurve' + '.cv[0:]',fl=True)
    for p in curveCVs:
        cmds.cluster(p)

def groupClusters(*args):
    cmds.group(n='clusterGrp',empty=True,world=True)
    #cmds.parent('clustersWhenProperlyRenamed','clusterGrp')
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: 1. You want to cluster only the top two and bottom two cvs.. so why not just do that? What's the issue? 2. The docs show that cluster has a name parameter.. did you try it? 3. Yes you can parent a cluster through code without creating that extra transform. Make sure you parent the cluster's handle. Careful that you don't use Stack Overflow as a crutch, because you're asking for help at practically every step of the way, it's not how to learn.

Comment: Fair enough, fortunately I was able to figure it out on my own. I usually post these questions as a failsafe incase I cant figure it out in my limited free time, that and I like to study other's approach to the problem. Usually when I make a script I try to anticipate the parts I think will cause me the most trouble beforehand. In this case it was joints between locators: renaming duplicated children, and clusters being weird. Even if I still figure it out on my own, I like to leave these questions up in hopes somebody else can read my dumbed down coding and avoid the same mistakes I made.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a solution I came up with for anyone curious:

```
'''
import DS_clusterCurve_demo
reload (DS_clusterCurve_demo)
DS_clusterCurve_demo.gui()
'''

import re
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

if cmds.window("clusterWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("clusterWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("clusterWin",t='DS_clusterCurve_demo',w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

def gui():
    if cmds.window("clusterWin", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("clusterWin", window=True)

    myWindow = cmds.window("clusterWin", t="DS_clusterCurve_demo", w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
    column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)

    cmds.button(label="Build Example curve", c=buildExamples)
    cmds.separator(w=200, h=3)
    cmds.button(label="Create Curve Clusters", c=buildClusters)
    cmds.separator(w=200, h=3)
    cmds.button(label="Group Clusters", c=groupClusters)

    cmds.setParent("..")
    cmds.showWindow(myWindow)

def buildExamples(*args):
    cmds.curve(n='guideLine_ctrlCurve', d=1, p=[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,2,0),(0,3,0)])

def buildClusters(*args):
    guideCurve = 'guideLine_ctrlCurve'
    cmds.cluster(guideCurve + ".cv[0:1]",n="up_crvCluster_")
    cmds.cluster(guideCurve + ".cv[2:3]",n="dwn_crvCluster_")

def groupClusters(*args):
    cmds.group(n='clusterGrp',empty=True,world=True)
    cmds.parent('up_crvCluster_Handle','clusterGrp')
    cmds.parent('dwn_crvCluster_Handle','clusterGrp')
```

It's more hardcoded than I would've preferred: but hey, if it works right?

Comment: `buildClusters` looks good, but you might need a check to see if the curve does have at least 4 points otherwise it would fail as it's assuming it does. It might make more sense to combine `buildClusters` and `groupClusters`, then you can capture the clusters in a variable and parent with that, because yes, `groupClusters` is hard-coded.

Comment: Another side note, notice that the code errors out the 2nd time it runs? That should be a hint that it's too hard-coded and should be adjusted.